# How does Concurrency Limit work in MassTransit RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am reading about [Concurrency Limit](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/concurrency-limit.html) in MassTransit RabbitMQ, but I am still not understanding how it really works.

Supposing I have 4 consumers and I configure the queues with concurrency limit to 1 `config.UseConcurrencyLimit(1);`. When a producer dispatch 4 messages at the same time, what will happen? Just one message will be consumed in just one consumer and all other 3 messages will be discarted?

Could someone explain me how does it work?

Comment: It would be a pretty lame - not to mention useless! - message queueing system if it just discarded messages.  This is a _concurrency_ limit: how many messages can be "in process" at a time.  When you hit the limit the other messages are kept in the queue until a worker frees up.

Comment: Though w.r.t. 4 consumers w/ concurrency limit 1 - that doc you linked implies that you couldn't have created 4 consumers if the concurrency limit is 1.  Someone who knows more can answer that (or you could experiment and report back).

Comment: So it also limits the number of concurrent consumers I have consuming the messages? Then If I have 4 consumers and concurrency limit to 1, only one consumer will be consuming the messages at a time. Once a message is consumed, the next one will be consumed and go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concurrency limit setting applies to the concurrency filter in GreenPipes. It sets a limit on a single consume pipe, which is a pipe for a single **consumer type**.

It basically tells MassTransit how many (competing) consumers **of the same type** it can instantiate to handle messages **of the same type** in parallel.

As rightfully mentioned in the question comments, there's no such thing as "discarding messages" in queueing. Even if you set the limit to one and publish 1000 messages, they will be processed, in this case, one by one.